# Unify divs so that resizing window does not disjoin them

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am trying to create a form with html and css. I have the impression that I must be using percentages and not pixels and I am in a way. I am using minimum widths etc. This is best described by a picture so I will provide it here.

This is in its base form:
[image]

And here is when I manipulate the window size:
[image]

Obviously I do not want my logos going off to the side and all about the place like depicted here. So here is my attempt at trying to reason with the logic involved in this "union" of div and input field.

Here is the html involved in the form, it has some manual styling, that is why I include it.

```
<div class="email-container">
    <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #3684FF">SEND ME AN EMAIL</h3>
    <form id="contact-form" action="//formspree.io/example@gmail.com" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="icon-case" id="iname">
                <i class="fa fa-user" id="user"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" onfocus="chbgn('#3684FF');" onblur="outblurn();" id="name" name="name" placeholder="FULL NAME" style="width: 36%; max-width: 36%; margin-right: 7.5%;">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="icon-case" id="iemail">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope" id="envelope"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" onfocus="chbge('#3684FF');" onblur="outblure();" id="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS" style="width: 36%; max-width: 37%;">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="icon-case" id="isubj">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil" id="pencil"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" onfocus="chbgs('#3684FF');" onblur="outblurs();" id="subj" name="_subject" placeholder="SUBJECT" style="width: 90%; max-width: 90%; overflow: hidden;">
        </div>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="SEND ME A MESSAGE . . ." style="height:150px; width:100%;"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" id="send" value="SUBMIT">
        <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="//example.com/thankyou.html" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS usage:

```
.email-container {
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    min-height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2% 5%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.icon-case {
    width: 5%;
    min-width: 5%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}

input[type=text] {
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    resize: none;
    float: left;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #3684FF;
}

input[type=submit] {
    padding: 8px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 37px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    background-color: none;
    color: #3684FF;
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #3684FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
}
```

As you can see I tried to go for minimum width/maximum width, float left... etc. What is the secret technique to getting this to condense cleanly? This is all happening in the body, and the body is 60% in width.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your CSS that I can see at quick glance, but I won't go into great detail as this is not how I would do it: you're floating both the icon and the input, and neither is positioned. That's guaranteed to be problematic. I also can't see any CSS for the form-group DIVs. In fact, none of your CSS selectors have `display` or `position` defined, and only the icon has `width`. These are pretty much essential as a starting point for good control.

A better way to place the icons and ensure they "stick" with their inputs is to make the inputs span the width of their form-group DIVs, and place the icons with `position: absolute;` inside the inputs, aligned to the left input edge. The input should be given enough `padding-left` to compensate for the intruding icon.

I have forgotten how Bootstrap does it, but you may like to go to their site and inspect their form elements of this kind. Their method might be as I described above or something different. If you get stuck rolling your own, an easy option is simply to use Bootstrap.